# Change iOS components value dynamically (Generic Programming)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, components, uislider, generic-programming

To make a generic code, i need to dispatch a value to a component, whatever the type of the component (`UISlider`,`UITextField`,`UIWebView` etc ...)

**Problem :**
Sometimes,`UIControl` manage an Object type (`NSString * for UITextField`), and sometimes a primitive type (float for UISlider).

My Dispatcher class that dispatch a value to a component knows only : 
* The setter to use to set a value to a component (example : `@selector(setText:)` for`UITextField`)
* The value to set

It uses KVO/KVC and i only can manipulate (id) type (so objects type because id can't hide a primitive type).

How could dispatch a float value to a UISlider to be generic ? 
the only way i achieve this for now is to create a category on`UISlider` that manages an object type and to inherit UISlider to override `setValue:animated` and "value" to uses my object type setter (`setObjectValue:` and "objectValue") :

**UISlider+DataObjet.h :**

```
@interface UISlider (DataObject)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *objectValue;

@end


@interface MFSlider : UISlider

@end
```

**UISlider+DataObject.m :**

```
#import "UISlider+DataObject.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void * objectValueIdentifier = &objectValueIdentifier;

@implementation UISlider (DataObject)

-(void)setObjectValue:(NSNumber *)value{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &objectValueIdentifier, value,  OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSNumber *)objectValue {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &objectValueIdentifier);
}

@end

@implementation MFSlider

-(void)setValue:(float)value animated:(BOOL) animated{
    [super setValue:value animated:animated];
    [self setObjectValue:@(value)];
}

-(float)value {
    return [[self objectValue] floatValue];
}

@end
```

It works, but i won't inherits`UISlider` to allow users to use basic`UISlider` instead`MFSlider` in storyboards... And i can't override basic implementation of`UISlider` methods in my category (without looping ...)

Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: Actually, you can kinda override implementation of `UISlider` methods in category. Take a look at method swizzling http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Comment: It's an interesting approach but i juste found my problem. I used performSelevtor:withObject to update the 'value' property instead of using "setValue:forKey" with a NSNumber * value and the key 'value'. KVC automatically converts object types into primitive types if necessery ; performing a selector does not call "'setValue:ForKey" ...